Binding dataframe with each clip of an actionButton in Shiny
A piece of an app I am building takes input from clip which is designed for excel tables on clipboard. I want it to be converted to data.frame using clipr::read_clip_tbl(). This works well. But, for each time the clip  actionButton is triggered, I want the output from table2 to be updated by binding the rows from each dataframe when clip is clicked. Instead, each time clip is triggered, it only shows the most recent data frame.
Any advice?
This is the part in question:
  c <- reactiveValues(value=0)

  observeEvent(input$clip, {
    c$value <- c$value+1
  })

  table2 <- eventReactive(input$clip, {
      read_clip_tbl() %>%
      mutate(exp = c$value) %>%
      bind_rows()
  })

But this is the full code:
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(clipr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    actionButton('clip', 'Copy from clipboard'),
    actionButton("go", "Go")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$style(type="text/css",
               ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
               ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
    ),
    
    plotOutput('plot1'),
  tableOutput( 'table1'), 
  tableOutput( 'table2')
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  c <- reactiveValues(value=0)
  
  observeEvent(input$clip, {
    c$value <- c$value+1
  })
  
  table2 <- eventReactive(input$clip, {
      read_clip_tbl() %>%
      mutate(exp = c$value) %>%
      bind_rows()
  })
  plot1 <- eventReactive(input$go, {
   read_clip_tbl() %>%
      mutate(treatment.name = as.factor(treatment.name)) %>%
      mort(plot_only=T)
  
    })
  table1 <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    read_clip_tbl() %>%
      mutate(treatment.name = as.factor(treatment.name)) %>%
      mort(table_only=T)
  })
  output$table2<- renderTable({
    req(table2())
    table2()
  })
    output$plot1<- renderPlot({
      req(plot1())
      plot1()
    })
    output$table1<- renderTable({
      req(table1())
      table1()
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)


I got it. I turned the dataframe into a reactiveValue.
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(clipr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    actionButton('clip', 'Copy from clipboard'),
    actionButton("go", "Go")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$style(type="text/css",
               ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
               ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
    ),
    
    plotOutput('plot1'),
  tableOutput( 'table1'), 
  tableOutput( 'table2')
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  comb <- data.frame
  c <- reactiveValues(value=0)
  prev <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame())
  
  observeEvent(input$clip, {
    c$value <- c$value+1
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$clip, {
    new <- read_clip_tbl()%>%
    mutate(exp = c$value)
    prev$data <- rbind(prev$data, new)
  })

  table2 <- eventReactive(input$clip, {
      prev$data 
  })
  plot1 <- eventReactive(input$go, {
   read_clip_tbl() %>%
      mutate(treatment.name = as.factor(treatment.name)) %>%
      mort(plot_only=T)
  
    })
  table1 <- eventReactive(input$go, {
    read_clip_tbl() %>%
      mutate(treatment.name = as.factor(treatment.name)) %>%
      mort(table_only=T)
  })


  output$table2<- renderTable({
    req(table2())
    table2()
  })
  


    output$plot1<- renderPlot({
      req(plot1())
      plot1()
    })
 
    


    output$table1<- renderTable({
      req(table1())
      table1()
    })
    
 

   
  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)

